# How do you set up watchers in Webstorm?

Tags: pug, webstorm, file-watcher

I keep getting message boxes suggesting that I should install file watchers. When I click 'Add Watcher' and press 'OK' on the dialog it gives the error...

> Please set program to run

Where do I get the programs from?

Comment: File Watcher is just a convenience tool that will launch specified program whenever your file gets modified/saved. So .. if you want setup a watcher to compile your `.less` files into `.css` you will need to have LESS compiler installed on your system.

Comment: If it knows there's a watcher then it ought to help me install it!

Answer (score 6):

1) not sure why the below instruction does not show how to install jade program. So Sebastian K is right, install

> npm install jade -g

the location for windows is this - remember this installed location of jade

> C:\Users\lee\AppData\Roaming\npm\jade.cmd

2) follow instruction https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/new-watcher-dialog.html

3) see attachment to confirm if it works.

[image]

Comment: In new version of pug should be use pug-cli

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps somebody you would have to follow this slightly less than obvious procedure:

Install Jade globally using npm:

```
npm install jade -g
```

This will actually drop some extra files in your node (or in my case nodist) directory that you will need to set up the watcher.

Set up the watcher by entering following path (tweaked for your own environment):

```
"c:\Program Files\nodist\bin\jade.cmd"
```

for "Program" setting under Watcher configuration for Jade in WebStorm.
For the rest of the settings you can leave the defaults.